# Select options dependent on select choice

Tags: javascript, html, select

So here's my idea:

```
<select id="Main_body">
<option value="1">Alpha</option>
<option value="2">Beta</option>
</select>

<select id="Sub1">
<option value="11">Omega</option>
<option value="12">Gamma</option>
</select>

<select id="Sub2">
<option value="21">Foxtrot</option>
<option value="22">Kilo</option>
</select>
```

If I select "Alpha" in the "Main_Body" option, then I will get the choices of the "Sub1" category.  If I select "Beta" then "Sub2" options will show.

Is there any way to do this in javascript?  If so, please help me.  Thank you everyone

Comment: share your code attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use the display: because the visibility is only hidden.
You can look at 
JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/anyuc7/sjyuo685/1/

```
var sub1=document.getElementById("Sub1"),
    sub2=document.getElementById("Sub2"),
    Main_body = document.getElementById("Main_body");
sub2.style.display = 'none';
Main_body.onchange = function (){
    if(this.value == 1){
        sub2.style.display = 'none';
        sub1.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }else{
        sub1.style.display = 'none';
        sub2.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the visibility of your select element according to the selected option.

***javaScript :***

```
document.getElementById("Sub2").style.visibility = 'hidden';

var mainDDL = document.getElementById("Main_body");

mainDDL.onchange = function(){
    // first hide both select element
    document.getElementById("Sub1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("Sub2").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    // check the currently selected options value and make the matched valued element visible
    if(this.value == 1){     
        document.getElementById("Sub1").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else{    
        document.getElementById("Sub2").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
};
```

you can also retrieve the text of the selected option and show/hide the required select element accordingly. In that case replace the if-else block with the code below,

```
// get the selected options text
var selectedOption = this.options[this.value - 1].text;

// show/hide select element according to the match with the selected option
if(selectedOption  == "Alpha"){     
    document.getElementById("Sub1").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
else{    
    document.getElementById("Sub2").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/83yxsru8/)